# Intercept HTTP Response Headers from embedded video GET request on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

My site hosts a video which is embedded into the page using a wrapper:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
            <div width="560" height="349" class="PingVP lead" data-language="Dutch" data-controls="below" data-autoStart="false" data-video="a_02_11_0009"></div>
 </div>
```

Everytime a visitor interacts with the video a HTTP Request/Response takes place. There is data in the Response Headers that I would like to extract every time a user interacts.

All the data is included as query parameters like this:

```
/a.php?1=0009&2=exxxxxx7-2xx2-1xx6-axx5-0xxxxxxxxxxe&3=3440&4=1440&5=a_02_11_0009&6=bxxxxxxd-xxxx-1xx6-bxxc-0xxxxxxxxxxe&7=Pause&8=1.63&11=&callback=pingVpEventC_1&_=1477043454075
```

I am unable to insert any XMLHttpRequest functions into the call since the video is hosted by a third party.

Is it possible to build a listener/parser for the response headers using Javascript/jQuery?